# To use mem and then find or to use find and handle the exception?

Tags: exception, ocaml

Suppose, I want to write a function that tries to find a key in a map and returns `None` if it cannot: `try_find: 'a -> ('a, 'b) Map.t -> 'b option`, what is the canonical way to do this? To first check that the key exists with `mem` and then call `find`? Or to catch the `Not_found` exception? Batteries seem to do the latter.

On the other hand, in languages like C# or Java people are usually discouraged from using exceptions in such cases, for performance reasons. Is using exceptions on "normal" execution paths a usual thing in Ocaml or is it also discouraged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml exceptions are as fast as function calls for the default backend. For Javascript backends, it is not always true. The canonical OCaml way is to implement a function that doesn't throw an exception is to use a throwing function and translate the exception to a nullary variant, e.g.,

```
let try_find x xs = try Some (List.find x xs) with Not_found -> None
```

Calling `mem` and `find` is a loss of performance, as you will actually iterate the list twice.

There are tradeoffs between raising an exception and returning an option type. The standard function `List.find` will not allocate any new values in the heap, so no garbage will be created. On the other hand, the `try_find` function will allocate a new value every time something is found (`None` is a constant so it is not allocated). This will create an extra work for the garbage collector, that will eventually degrade the performance. To me, the semantic benefits of total functions outweigh possible performance degradation. If the latter does matter (in case of tight loops) then I can always optimize it locally by either using an exception in a very tight context, or continuation passing style and/or GADT.

> Is using exceptions on "normal" execution paths a usual thing in Ocaml or is it also discouraged?

It wasn't discouraged by the design of the language, and OCaml standard library uses exceptions a lot. However, the language evolves, and new features are added to the language. Moreover, new backends are implemented, like several Javascript backends, Java, and .Net backends. It is not trivial, to provide the same performance guarantees for these backends. So with a time, the popularity of exceptions reduced, and many people started to favor total functions with explicitly encoded errors, cf., the newly added to the standard library `result` type. Another example is Janestreet Core library (and all other libraries) that disfavor exceptions and use them only for exceptional cases.

You should decide by yourself an exception policy (or borrow the existing one). My personal policy is trying to avoid them in the public interfaces and sparingly use them very locally. I also use exceptions, for logic and programmer errors, basically, for errors, that shouldn't be captured.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, OCaml exceptions are quite efficient, and I see them being used more often than in other functional languages I guess.

I try to avoid them myself as they interfere with reasoning about the program. But a self-contained use in a library doesn't seem so bad.

The efficiency of low-level things like exceptions is something that might vary a lot from platform to platform. I suspect that catching the `Not_found` exception would be faster for very large maps, as it avoids traversing the map twice. Otherwise it might not matter much.